# Connect .Net Core App in Google App Engine to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core-mvc, google-cloud-sql

Using the recommended way of connecting a .Net application running in App Engine Flexible [.Net to SQL AppEngine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-cloud-sql) (all networks allowed to connect to MySql Instance with SSL) we saw many unauthenticated logon attempts that we assume have caused some of our connection issues recently.

Is there no better(More Secure) way to connect?

Can't we use Google Cloud SQL Proxy to rather connect and limit authorized networks using standard capability?

Comment: Ran into same problem, did you encounter a solution?

Comment: Yea, we just ran the application in k8s with a service running sql proxy. The frontend still runs on app engine flex.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to using .Net Core apps in AppEngine Flex and connect to your CloudSQL instances is to use a implementation of cloudsql proxy.